# Remove "New Lead" button from custom object page layout

Tags: lightning, custom-object, page-layout, leads, button

I want to remove "New Lead" button from a page layout of custom object.
This object is not related to Lead but the button gets displayed by default.

I have checked the page layout and the new lead button is not added from Mobile & Lightning actions

Custom Object-> Page Layouts -> Mobile & Lightning Actions --> New Lead button is not included in the buttons.
Its not included in the Standard buttons section as well.

Comment: Can you check the custom object have lightning record page.

Comment: It does have a Lightning Record Page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The 'New Lead' button was anchored in a Global Publisher Layout. After adjusting the layout, the button was no longer visible.